# EclipseRCP: Running a system command and print output in custom Console

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a custom console in eclipse by extending IOConsole using the following code.

```
IConsoleManager consoleManager = ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager();
IOConsole console = new MyConsole("My Custom Console", null);
consoleManager.addConsoles(new IConsole[] { console });
```

The console is getting created properly and i am able to view the console in the list of consoles displayed in the RCP application.

I want to run a system command and want to associate the output in the custom console in **REALTIME**. I have written the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
IConsole[] consoles = plugin.getConsoleManager().getConsoles();
for (IConsole iConsole : consoles) {
    if (iConsole instanceof MyConsole) {
        console = (MyConsole) iConsole;
        break;
    }
}
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("mvn --version");
console.setInputStream(process.getInputStream());
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a separate `Thread`in which you would:

- create a new `OutputStream` for the `IOConsole` that you have using `IOConsole#newOutputStream()`
- read from the running process `InputStream` and write the bytes in the console using the aforementioned `outputStream`, until the process exited.

Comment: I have tried to do the same by using the following code.
`code`(
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("python"/*command.getCommand()*/);
console.setInputStream(process.getInputStream());
IOConsoleOutputStream newOutputStream = console.newOutputStream();
newOutputStream.setActivateOnWrite(true);
while (process.isAlive()) {
      IOUtils.copy(process.getInputStream(), newOutputStream);
})

But it just got indefinitely stuck while trying to copy InputStream to OutputStream using IOUtils.copy(). Am i doing something wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know might be a bit too late, but the easiest is to create an external launch configuration, put the proper settings, run it and remove it later on. Like his, the console will be updated automatically, you can cancel the excecution etc.
More info on: http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/11/23/writing-an-eclipse-plugin/

Basically:

ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
            ILaunchConfigurationType programType = manager
                    .getLaunchConfigurationType(IExternalToolConstants.ID_PROGRAM_LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_TYPE);

```
        ILaunchConfiguration cfg = programType.newInstance(null, "YourCommandName");
        ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy wc = cfg.getWorkingCopy();
        wc.setAttribute(IExternalToolConstants.ATTR_LOCATION, "${system_path:" + systemCommand+ "}");
        wc.setAttribute(IExternalToolConstants.ATTR_WORKING_DIRECTORY, directoryToStartFrom);
        wc.setAttribute(IExternalToolConstants.ATTR_TOOL_ARGUMENTS, parametersToPass);
        cfg = wc.doSave();
        cfg.launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null, false, true);
        cfg.delete();
```